# Google Maps SDK for Android: Smoothly animating the camera to a new location, rendering all the tiles along the way

Tags: java, android, react-native, google-maps-android-api-2, react-native-component

#### Background

Many similar questions seem to have been asked on SO before (most notably [android google maps not loading the map when using GoogleMap.AnimateCamera()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58230401/android-google-maps-not-loading-the-map-when-using-googlemap-animatecamera) and [How can I smoothly pan a GoogleMap in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837133/how-can-i-smoothly-pan-a-googlemap-in-android/33837696#33837696)), but none of the answers or comments posted throughout those threads have given me a firm idea of how to do this.

I initially thought that it would be as simple as just calling `animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(), duration, callback)` but like the OP of the first link above, all I get is a gray or very blurry map until the animation completes, **even if I slow it down to tens of seconds long!**

I've managed to find and implement [this helper class](https://github.com/antoniocarlon/MapUtils/blob/master/src/map/CameraUpdateAnimator.java) that does a nice job of allowing the tiles to render along the way, but even with a delay of 0, there is a noticeable lag between each animation.

#### Code

OK, time for some code. Here's the (slightly-modified) helper class:

```
package com.coopmeisterfresh.googlemaps.NativeModules;

import android.os.Handler;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CameraUpdateAnimator implements GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener {
    private final GoogleMap mMap;
    private final GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener mOnCameraIdleListener;

    private final List<Animation> cameraUpdates = new ArrayList<>();

    public CameraUpdateAnimator(GoogleMap map, GoogleMap.
        OnCameraIdleListener onCameraIdleListener) {
        mMap = map;
        mOnCameraIdleListener = onCameraIdleListener;
    }

    public void add(CameraUpdate cameraUpdate, boolean animate, long delay) {
        if (cameraUpdate != null) {
            cameraUpdates.add(new Animation(cameraUpdate, animate, delay));
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        cameraUpdates.clear();
    }

    public void execute() {
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(this);
        executeNext();
    }

    private void executeNext() {
        if (cameraUpdates.isEmpty()) {
            mOnCameraIdleListener.onCameraIdle();
        } else {
            final Animation animation = cameraUpdates.remove(0);

            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                if (animation.mAnimate) {
                    mMap.animateCamera(animation.mCameraUpdate);
                } else {
                    mMap.moveCamera(animation.mCameraUpdate);
                }
            }, animation.mDelay);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        executeNext();
    }

    private static class Animation {
        private final CameraUpdate mCameraUpdate;
        private final boolean mAnimate;
        private final long mDelay;

        public Animation(CameraUpdate cameraUpdate, boolean animate, long delay) {
            mCameraUpdate = cameraUpdate;
            mAnimate = animate;
            mDelay = delay;
        }
    }
}
```

And my code to implement it:

```
// This is actually a React Native Component class, but I doubt that should matter...?
public class NativeGoogleMap extends SimpleViewManager<MapView> implements
    OnMapReadyCallback, OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    // ...Other unrelated methods removed for brevity

    private void animateCameraToPosition(LatLng targetLatLng, float targetZoom) {
        // googleMap is my GoogleMap instance variable; it
        // gets properly initialised in another class method
        CameraPosition currPosition = googleMap.getCameraPosition();
        LatLng currLatLng = currPosition.target;
        float currZoom = currPosition.zoom;

        double latDelta = targetLatLng.latitude - currLatLng.latitude;
        double lngDelta = targetLatLng.longitude - currLatLng.longitude;

        double latInc = latDelta / 5;
        double lngInc = lngDelta / 5;

        float zoomInc = 0;
        float minZoom = googleMap.getMinZoomLevel();
        float maxZoom = googleMap.getMaxZoomLevel();

        if (lngInc > 15 && currZoom > minZoom) {
            zoomInc = (minZoom - currZoom) / 5;
        }

        CameraUpdateAnimator animator = new CameraUpdateAnimator(googleMap,
            () -> googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(
            targetZoom), 5000, null));

        for (double nextLat = currLatLng.latitude, nextLng = currLatLng.
            longitude, nextZoom = currZoom; Math.abs(nextLng) < Math.abs(
            targetLatLng.longitude);) {
            nextLat += latInc;
            nextLng += lngInc;
            nextZoom += zoomInc;

            animator.add(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new
                LatLng(nextLat, nextLng), (float)nextZoom), true);
        }

        animator.execute();
    }
}
```

#### Question

Is there a better way to accomplish this seemingly-simple task? I'm thinking that perhaps I need to move my animations to a worker thread or something; would that help?

Thanks for reading (I know it was an effort :P)!

#### Update 30/09/2021

I've updated the code above in line with Andy's suggestions in the comments and although it works (albeit with the same lag and rendering issues), the final algorithm will need to be a bit more complex since I want to zoom out to the longitudinal delta's half-way point, then back in as the journey continues.

Doing all these calculations at once, as well as smoothly rendering all the necessary tiles **simultaneously**, seems to be way too much for the cheap mobile phone that I'm testing on. Or is this a limitation of the API itself? In any case, how can I get all of this working **smoothly, without any lag whatsoever between queued animations?**

Comment: Just to clarify - is it a requirement that you must maintain the target zoom level throughout the map traverse?

Comment: I'm glad you asked! I wanted to mention this aspect of the problem but my WOT was already taller than the Sears Tower! :P What I'd **really** like to do is have the same effect as Google Earth, i.e. zoom out to max height then back in to target height as the traversal occurs. I've tried some simple test implementations of this idea, but they all failed abysmally. So I decided to simplify the problem and focus on the most important aspect first ;-)

Comment: The GE reference was exactly what I was thinking - the intent of this is to greatly reduce (exponentially) the tile rendering during the traverse.  If I recall - it has a bouncing ball effect - it is zooming out while traversing - so I'm thinking you could add that to your "series animator" - change zoom (out) half-way there - and back in second half - but use the same executor concept you have.

Comment: Hmm interesting...yes of course it would greatly reduce the amount of tile rending necessary; I can't believe I didn't realise that myself! *forehead slap* My brain kinda started to melt when I attempted to implement that effect though (LOL), so I decided to just move on. Now you've made me realise that it will actually make the whole thing **immensely** faster, so it's worth trying again! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt using your utility frame player.

A few notes:

- The zoom value is interpolated based on the total steps (set at 500 here) and given the start and stop values.
- A Google Maps utility is used to compute the next lat lng based on a fractional distance: `SphericalUtil.interpolate`.
- The fractional distance should not be a linear function to reduce the introduction of new tiles.  In other words, at higher zooms (closer in) the camera moves in shorter distances and the amount of camera movement increases exponentially (center-to-center) while zooming out.  This requires a bit more explanation...
- As you can see the traversal is split into two - reversing the exponential function of the distance movement.
- The "max" zoom (bad name) which is the furthest out can be a function of the total distance - computed to encompass the whole path at the midpoint.  For now it's hard coded to 4 for this case.
- Note the maps `animate` function *cannot* be used as it introduces its own bouncing ball effect *on each step* which is undesirable.  So given a fair number of steps the `move` function can be used.
- This method attempts to minimize tile loading per step but ultimately the TileLoader is the limiting factor for viewing which cannot monitored (easily).

## animateCameraToPosition

```
// flag to control the animate callback (at completion).
boolean done = false;

private void animateCameraToPosition(LatLng targetLatLng, float targetZoom) {
    CameraPosition currPosition = gMap.getCameraPosition();
    LatLng currLatLng = currPosition.target;

    //meters_per_pixel = 156543.03392 * Math.cos(latLng.lat() * Math.PI / 180) / Math.pow(2, zoom)
    int maxSteps = 500;
    // number of steps between start and midpoint and midpoint and end
    int stepsMid = maxSteps / 2;

    // current zoom
    float initz = currPosition.zoom;
    //TODO maximum zoom (can be computed from overall distance) such that entire path
    //     is visible at midpoint.
    float maxz = 4.0f;
    float finalz = targetZoom;

    CameraUpdateAnimator animator = new CameraUpdateAnimator(gMap, () -> {
        if (!done) {
            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.
                    zoomTo(targetZoom), 5000, null);
        }
        done = true;

    });

    // loop from start to midpoint

    for (int i = 0; i < stepsMid; i++) {
        // compute interpolated zoom (current --> max) (linear)
        float z = initz - ((initz - maxz) / stepsMid) * i;

        // Compute fractional distance using an exponential function such that for the first
        // half the fraction delta advances slowly and accelerates toward midpoint.
        double ff = (i * (Math.pow(2,maxz) / Math.pow(2,z))) / maxSteps;

        LatLng nextLatLng =
                SphericalUtil.interpolate(currLatLng, targetLatLng, ff);
        animator.add(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                nextLatLng, z), false, 0);
    }

    // loop from midpoint to final
    for (int i = 0; i < stepsMid; i++) {
        // compute interpolated zoom (current --> max) (linear)
        float z = maxz + ((finalz - maxz) / stepsMid) * i;
        double ff = (maxSteps - ((i+stepsMid) * ( (Math.pow(2,maxz) / Math.pow(2,z)) ))) / (double)maxSteps;

        LatLng nextLatLng =
                SphericalUtil.interpolate(currLatLng, targetLatLng, ff);

        animator.add(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                nextLatLng, z), false, 0);
    }

    animator.add(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            targetLatLng, targetZoom), true, 0);

    //

    animator.execute();
}
```

## Test Code

I tested with these two points (and code) from Statue Of Liberty to a point on the west coast:

```
gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(40.68924, -74.04454), 13.0f));

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            animateCameraToPosition(new LatLng(33.899832, -118.020450), 13.0f);
        }
    }, 5000);
```

## CameraUpdateAnimator Mods

I modified the camera update animator slightly:

```
public void execute() {
    mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(this);
    executeNext();
}

private void executeNext() {
    if (cameraUpdates.isEmpty()) {
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mOnCameraIdleListener);
        mOnCameraIdleListener.onCameraIdle();
    } else {
        final Animation animation = cameraUpdates.remove(0);
        // This optimization is likely unnecessary since I think the
        // postDelayed does the same on a delay of 0 - execute immediately.
        if (animation.mDelay > 0) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                if (animation.mAnimate) {
                    mMap.animateCamera(animation.mCameraUpdate);
                } else {
                    mMap.moveCamera(animation.mCameraUpdate);
                }
            }, animation.mDelay);
        } else {
            if (animation.mAnimate) {
                mMap.animateCamera(animation.mCameraUpdate);
            } else {
                mMap.moveCamera(animation.mCameraUpdate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Before Sample

Using

```
// assume initial (40.68924, -74.04454) z=13.0f
gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(33.899832,-118.020450), 13.0f), 30000, null);
```

[image]

## After Samples

*These are recorded from an emulator.  I also sideloaded onto my phone (Samsumg SM-G960U) with similar results (using 1000 steps 0 delay).*

*So I don't think this meets your requirements entirely: there are some "ambiguous tiles" as they are brought in from the west.*

Statue of Liberty - to - somewhere near San Diego

500 Steps 0 delay
 [image]

100 Steps 0 delay
 [image]

50 Steps 100MS delay
 [image]

---

## Diagnostics

It is in some ways useful to have insight into what Maps is doing with tiles.  Insight can be provided by installing a simple `UrlTileProvider` and log the requests.  This implementation fetches the google tiles though they are lower resolution that is normally seen.

To do this the following is required:

```
    // Turn off this base map and install diagnostic tile provider
    gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
    gMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(new MyTileProvider(256,256)).fadeIn(true));
```

And define the diagnostic file provider

```
public class MyTileProvider extends UrlTileProvider {

    public MyTileProvider(int i, int i1) {
        super(i, i1);
    }

    @Override
    public URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {

        Log.i("tiles","x="+x+" y="+y+" zoom="+zoom);

        try {
            return new URL("http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x="+x+"&y="+y+"&z="+zoom);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

You'll notice right away that tile layers are always defined in integral units (`int`).  The fractional zooms which are supplied in the zoom (e.g. `LatLngZoom` work strictly with the in-memory images - good to know.'

Here's a sample for completeness:

```
// initial zoom 
x=2411 y=3080 zoom=13
x=2410 y=3080 zoom=13
x=2411 y=3081 zoom=13
x=2410 y=3081 zoom=13
x=2411 y=3079 zoom=13
x=2410 y=3079 zoom=13
```

And at max:

```
x=9 y=12 zoom=5
x=8 y=12 zoom=5
x=9 y=11 zoom=5
x=8 y=11 zoom=5
x=8 y=13 zoom=5
x=9 y=13 zoom=5
x=7 y=12 zoom=5
x=7 y=11 zoom=5
x=7 y=13 zoom=5
x=8 y=10 zoom=5
x=9 y=10 zoom=5
x=7 y=10 zoom=5
```

Here's a chart of the zooms (y-axis) at each invocation of tiler (x-axis).  Each zoom layer are *roughly* the same count which imo is what is desired.  The full-out zoom appears twice as long because that's the midpoint repeating.  There are a few anomalies though which require explaining (e.g. at around 110).

This is a chart of "zoom" as logged by the tile provider.  So each x-axis point would represent a single tile fetch.

[image]

Comment: OMG I'd given up all hope of anyone answering this question, even after posting the bounty since it took you so long to answer LOL. Now I can see that the reason for the delay is probably how hard you worked on the problem, while juggling all your normal life commitments as well. TYVM for going to so much effort!!  I don't have the time to test it now but at first glance your solution looks solid as a rock!  I'll try it myself tomorrow and it'll be interesting to see whether my phone is as poor-performing as I previously assumed.

Comment: Oh and I'd absolutely **love** some GIFs if that's not too difficult... you should be able to use an online tool to convert any screen recording into a GIF and *hopefully* that will help you get around the 2MB limit. Thanks again! 

Comment: Wow...I was already so, so pleased with your original answer but after adding the GIFs and tile fetching info I am absolutely blown away by the comprehensiveness of, and effort put into this post. I am forever in your debt and wish there was some way that I could upvote this a million times! Thank you so, so much! :D:D:D

Comment: OK after running your code through a few tests over a greater distance than yours, my phone definitely seems to be the main culprit of my entire problem :-( After all this effort on both our parts, I fear that I may have to abandon this entire feature of my app since I'd ideally like it to work on **any** phone, and for traversing up to a full 180° around the globe. I can't expect you to devote any more time to this, nor do I have the brain power to really understand your algorithm and improve it. I didn't think this would be such a complex problem 2 weeks ago but I was obviously wrong! :-(